# Why can't a macro-enabled workbook be moved to another folder with the "Name As" method in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, path, mkdir

The following code attempts to take a macro-enabled (.xlsm) workbook, create a folder with it's name in the same directory where the workbook is located, and then move the workbook into said folder and change its name.

```
        Dim xlsm_wb         As Workbook
        Dim xlsm_path       As String
        Dim xlsm_name       As String
        Dim fold_path       As String
               
        Set xlsm_wb = Application.Workbooks("repositorio nóminas.xlsm")
            xlsm_path = xlsm_wb.Path
            xlsm_name = xlsm_wb.FullName
            fold_path = xlsm_path & "\repositorio nóminas"
        
        Debug.Print xlsm_name
        Debug.Print fold_path & "\matenimiento.xlsm"
        
        MkDir fold_path                                                    <- Error 75 here 
        Name xlsm_name As fold_path & "\matenimiento.xlsm"                 <- or here
```

As you can see, I get error 75 in the second-to-last instruction, and if I comment it out and attempt to simply move the .xlsm into the folder without creating it manually, it also gives me the same error.

Comment: Is the code you posted in the workbook you're trying to move?   If so that's never going to work.  Best you could achieve is to save a copy of it in the new location.  If it's not the book containing the code, then close it before moving it.  You can open it again after moving it if you want to

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not letting me move the book is that in order to run the macro, the workbook has been opened, and an opened file cannot be moved while being used.